# Youtube API for getting replies to a comment

Tags: api, youtube

Is there any way by which I can get replies to a particular comment on youtube video using api?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The official YouTube v2.0 API documentation outlines how to do this.

In an XML response, a comment that was posted in response to another comment will contain an in-reply-to link as shown in the following  tag:

`<link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#in-reply-to"type="application/atom+xml" href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/2cd.../comments/978..."/>`

Full details are here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Retrieve_comments